# What Techniques Are Used for Signal / Image Denoising (Example Image Provided)?

Tags: image-processing, filters, lowpass-filter

I have an image that looks like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1X1jFSEgpjJNmMzZTZ6QkdSOTg/view?usp=sharing**) (it might appear low res in a browser because it is 16 MB). This image was taken with a scanning electron microscope, but because the equipment is outdated there is a lot of noise within the image.

What I would like to do is develop a program (in Java) that would take this image as an input and try to remove the noise as much as possible to produce a high quality image.

However, being a beginner in the field of image/signal processing, I have no idea where to begin researching techniques. I was wondering if you guys had any good starting points for me to look into, or perhaps de-noising algorithms/techniques that I could research to potentially help me reach my goal.

Comment: That doesn't look like noise to me – it's more like a very horizontal-periodic distortion. Try to look at the 2D DFT abs spectrum of the image. Then write a small program to do DFT->delete periodic component->IDFT. I honestly don't like Java, and I don't like it for signal processing especially, but I think there's a rather common library for analysis of (biological) microscope images, just can't think of the name.